# Recognize users redirected from social networks shared content

Tags: javascript, django, twitter, web, http-headers

I've been researching a lot and couldn't find anything close to my story. I'm stuck currently.

I need to figure out whether user comes to my website by clicking on shared content from social networks (Facebook, Twitter,Linkedin ) or user just accesses directly?

For instance, I shared my website on Facebook and some of my friends see it and click on the share content, so I want to recognize those users as user that are coming from social virality.

Any idea how it can be implemented ?

Comment: Dude, for social network, you can use flag in your url, so you can easily filter.

Comment: Sounds good. can u point me out to any example of it, please.

Comment: normal url: http://www.yourweb.com And social url:  http://www.yourweb.com?flag="social".

Comment: Then user will share on the twiiter  [yourweb.com?flag="social"](http://yourweb.com?flag="social"), which is not nice to be like this

Comment: Yes, it is but if you provide sharing option, then user only click on share button and the url with flag will posted.

Comment: That's ok. I will consider this solution.

Answer (score 1):

It can be implemented by checking the [Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) of incoming HTTP requests.

As the referer is a HTTP header, it can be accessed this way in Django:

```
referer = request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')
```

Beware that you cannot rely on the Referer header being correct as the user can change it or prevent it being sent.

Answer (score -1):

Try using Google analytics, it gives you all statistics like where visitor came from, what device your visitor use and much more. You can signup by below link

[www.google.com/analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics)

Let me know if you need some more input

Comment: That's ok, but I don't need it in that context. I need to display diff content on my web page if user comes from any social network.

Comment: oh sorry I misunderstood your question: may you can recognize by creating different links for social network, check query builder of https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en